# Python passing handle to interface to multiple modules

Tags: python, object

I have a python program with multiple modules. There is a module that contains code to initialize a UDP Interface to send messages. I would like this Interface to be used across all the modules. The only way I've thought of is passing the object to the other modules through a predefined function.

Main Module:

```
from mod1 import *
from mod2 import *
from Interfaces import *

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):

        # Initialize Modules
        self.m1 = Module1()
        self.m2 = Module2()

        self.intf = UdpInterface()
        self._init_module_interfaces()

    def _init_module_interfaces(self):
        self.m1.InitIntf(self.intf)
        self.m2.InitIntf(self.intf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = MainClass()
```

Submodule:

```
class Module1():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def InitIntf(self, intf):
        self.intf = intf
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to share your code!

Comment: @NikhilParmar Added some sample code.

Comment: Your "global variable will be namespaced in the module its in. You can explicitly include it into your other namespaces... `from mymodules.module2 import GLOBAL_VAR`

Comment: I think `from mod import *` is bad practice, as you can overwrite identifiers in your current namespace. Namespaces are good!

Comment: @CharlesAddis Are you saying I define a global variable in the MainModule namespace, assign the interface to that global. and that include the MainModule global in submodules?